# Using UDIDs or Serial Keys to provision iPads - AppStore approval

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, udid

I work for a company that makes kiosk applications. We currently use custom windows tablets for our kiosks, but we're planning to move to using an iPad for all our kiosk apps. We need to have one single app on the app store and the workflow that we show is customized based on client. We identify which client a request is coming from by the iPad's device identifier (udid). We associate this internally with a workflow on the server side and return the appropriate workflow.

So, to recap, we need to create workflows for each single iPad and the iPads are identified by deviceId. A valid workflow is needed by the device to start functioning. Ignoring that the UDID API has been deprecated for a minute, My question then is, does Apple allow this kind of deployment if we publish the app to the App Store?

Another alternate approach we were thinking about was to build a licensing infrastructure on our side. The client would get the iPad, call us for a license key and when the key is entered correctly, we populate our database with the deviceId and a workflow automatically.

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the mac address of the ipad form the webserver
you would normally present a normal application, you will need to add normal functionality to this application, such as information about the product or the company, or about how to register or buy, you will have to add some usability to it so that apple does not reject your app as being incomplete or a demo

After that you will need to register the mac address of the iPad and authenticate it on the server, if the ipad gets authenticated, then you will present the fully functional application that the kiosk buyers will use.

Hope this will help you